# Matlab executables, passing variable

Tags: matlab

How do I use deploytool to get an executable file from a .m function and use it?

say, I have a .m names foo, here is the code:

```
function product = foo(array_a,array_b)
product = array_a.*array_b
end
```

now I use deploytool to generate a foo.exe, how can I use it with the same workspace vars, AKA array_a and array_b?

Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got your code to work by just supplying the executable file with variables.

I first ran `mbuild -setup`. I have your file, called `foo2.m`:

```
function product = foo(array_a,array_b)
if ischar(array_a)
array_a = str2num(array_a);
end
if ischar(array_b)
array_b = str2num(array_b);
end

product = array_a.*array_b
end
```

The only difference is I ensured that the input are processed as numbers, not strings. Then, I compile:

```
mcc -mv -R -singleCompThread -N -p optim -p stats foo2.m
```

(A good explanation of this command is here: [MCC example](http://www.it.northwestern.edu/research/sscc/matlabcompiler.html). I used the link to help me get it working.)

Then, just execute the function.

```
./run_foo2.sh /usr/local/MATLAB/R2011a/ 1 2
```

....

```
product =
 2
```

Make sure you specify the location of the compiler libraries as the first argument, then array_a and array_b as the 2nd and 3rd arguments.

I first got an error when I tried to run the executable: `error while loading shared libraries: libmwmclmcrrt.so.7.15: cannot open shared object file`. I fixed this by finding the library file path (using `find . -name "libmwmclmcrrt.so*"`). I then corrected the library path I was supplying as the first argument when I called the executable.

Answer (score 1):

You can use *eval* to convert strings to other data types, such as arrays. See [here](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2011/01/06/matlab-data-types-as-arguments-to-standalone-applications/) for more details.

Also, *pcode* could be another way, if you want to protect your source code.